Deleting saved jobs in LinkedIn
I new to programming and still learning. I am trying to mass unsave jobs I have applied to via LinkedIn because for some reason the jobs that I apply for, don't go to applied jobs and remain in my saved jobs list. I have been trying to select the 3 dot drop down button and then click unsave but have been unsuccessful, wondering if anyone has an idea of where I am going wrong?
while not get_em:
    # Obtain links to all saved jobs
    job_elements = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.reusable-search__result-container a.app-aware-link')))
    links = [job_element.get_attribute("href") for job_element in job_elements]
    

    for jobs in job_elements:
        print("clicking 3 dot button")
        button = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'artdeco-dropdown__trigger ')
        button.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        print("clicking unsave button")
        xbutton = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'unsave-option-class')
        xbutton.click()
   
    # Go to the next page or end
    try:
        next_button = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.artdeco-pagination__button--next')))
        if next_button.is_displayed() and next_button.is_enabled():
            browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", next_button)   
            next_button.click()
            time.sleep(5)
            counter += 1
            print(f"Page number: {counter}")
            time.sleep(5)
       
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Next page button not found, at the end of all pages! or error occured:{e}")
        get_em = True

